# Java best practice: Nested maps

Tags: java

I need to store a table of data for something like the following:

> ID, Month, Value1, Value2

I am currently using:

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>
```

should I convert it to something like the following for readability:

```
List<ObjectA>
```

where:

```
public ObjectA {
    private ID;
    private Map<String, ObjectB> map;
}
public ObjectB {
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
}
```

Or would it be better practice to keep it in terms of basic java list and maps?

Comment: How many "values" is `ObjectA` likely to have? If it's only two, I don't see the point of `ObjectB`

Comment: There are over 50 IDs, the map inside of ObjectA is for data over the span of 3 years in month, so 36 items in each ObjectA.map. ObjectB only contains 2 value and nothing else, maybe I can simplify that?

Comment: I think for your own sanity, you should figure out how best to "represent" this data in an OO manner, as it will reduce the complexity and guess work in the long run - IMHO

Comment: What matters most is the end goal. How best to store/model data depends on what you will do with it. For example, a good place to start is to explain how you plan to access the data. Without knowing that, there is no "best" solution.

Comment: @tom 

If the `ID` is unique, I think It's better you use `Map` to replace for `List`
`Map<Integer, ObjectA>`

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely create a new object and store the entries in a list of objects or in a map, depending on how important is the ID and it's type.

The main reason for this is readability. The alternative is not only rather inelegant, but it is also quite hard to read and understand. Also, it scales extremely poorly: what if your objects had not only 3-4, but 10 attributes?

Another reason is semantics. Assuming the data is coming from a tabular form (e.g. relational database), the table should represent an entity, an each entry the properties of various entities. You loose this concept of "entity" and "propriety" if you are not using custom objects.

In some cases, when the properties (members) have the same type, a map *could* be an option. It might be easier from a development point of view, still captures some of the readability of "property", and if it is enclosed in an object that limits access (e.g. read only, don't insert other properties by mistake), can have a decent safety too.

Comment: Custom Class would be ideal. Agree  with @Paul92.

Answer (score -4):

You should probably stick to the "basic" and inherent Java data structures for the example you described.

Creating your own data structures (i.e. `Object A`) like you have give you a lot of freedom; especially once you start playing around with Java generics and things of that nature. However, the data structures that come native to Java and that are in the [Collections API](http://how2examples.com/java/collections) are already optimized and should be used whenever you can. Given the example you listed, it doesn't seem like you need too many crazy or super application specific functionalities (at least not *yet...*), so sticking with the "basic" classes and structures should work fine.

[See this post here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332297/how-why-or-when-would-you-use-your-own-data-structure-instead-of-collections-fr/332298) which explains why you should try to avoid creating your own data structures and classes if you can.

**TLDR: Use the "basic" inherent Java functionalities and features**

Comment: That's not a data structure. It's a simple class, which is perfectly common and recommended to model data.

Comment: Is the class itself not a logical structure to hold data, manage, and manipulate data? CLRS defines it as so.

Comment: Classes *are* in fact the most basic and most inherent part of Java

Comment: @JerryM. Perhaps, but that's not at all what's meant when people talk about designing custom data structures, as in the question you linked.